# How to solve these two equations for $\tau$ and $b$? All the other symbols are constants.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

$$\large{\frac{\mu b}2\frac{2-\nu}{1-\nu}R\ln\frac{R}{r_c}-\tau\pi R^2+\frac{\gamma_0\pi^2 R^2}{b_0}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi(u_0+b)}{b_0}\right)=0}$$

$$\large{\frac{\mu b^2}4\frac{2-\nu}{1-\nu}\left[1+\ln\frac{R}{r_c}\right]-2\pi R\tau b-\gamma_0\pi R\sin\left(\frac{\pi(2u_0+b)}{b_0}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi b}{b_0}\right)=0}$$

I've tried inputting the two equations in Mathematica but I think my input formatting is incorrect.

Comment: There is no hope to isolate $b$, since it appears both as an algebraic quantity and as the argument of a trigonometric function.

Comment: Why are you even trying to solve these? If you gave us more details, we could offer alternate possibilities

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We prefer to have all math here typed in MathJax, which isn't too hard to learn: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. If you click "edit," you can see how I used MathJax to type your equations.

Comment: Yeah I've seen the edit and it's pretty cool. Almost similar to LaTex formatting. I'll be mindful of this. Thanks!

Comment: You could try and solve it in the approximation of small $b/b_0$ then check that the solution is small when feeding in values for all the other constants.

Comment: $$\large{G=\frac{\mu b^2}{4} \frac{2-\nu}{1-\nu} \ln \frac{R}{r_c} - \tau b \pi R^2 + \pi R^2 \frac{\gamma_0}{2} [cos\frac{2\pi u_0}{b_0}-cos\frac{2 \pi (u_0+b)}{b_0}]}$$

the previous two equations are partial derivatives of this equation with respect to b & R respectively. The goal is to get $\tau$ and $b$ as functions of R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you re-write your equations to have coefficients $c_k$ instead of large expressions:

$$
c_1 b + c_2 \tau+c_3 \sin(c_4 +c_5 b) = 0
$$

$$
c_6 b^2 + c_7 b \tau+c_8 \sin(c_9 +c_{10} b) \sin(c_{11}b) = 0
$$

Now this should be much easier to write on Mathematica, and you can define each symbol and check for its appropriate typing.

Then, since the first equation looks a bit like [Kepler's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation), I would not hope to find an analytical solution, but depending on your coefficients you should be able to find a numeric solution with rather simple methods such as [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) or in the worst case [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have used newton raphson to numerically solve for 'b' & 'tau'.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mefitico's answer, extract $\tau$ from the first equation and plug the resulting expression in the second equation which is now on the form $f(b)=0$. Solve it for $b$ (I suppose that graphing the function would be a good idea to locate more or less where is the root) and use any numerical method of your choice for solving it.

No hope for analytical solutions.

Comment: I kind of knew analytical solution might be almost impossible to figure out. I have used newton raphson to solve for 'b' & tau' numerically. Thanks!!